# F# integer comparison

Tags: f#

Given a list int from -273 to 5526, I want to print the closest integer to zero. In case of you have equality (n and -n) we should take n.

```
let temps = // this contains => 1 -2 -8 4 5

let (|Greater|_|) a b = if a > b then Some() else None
let (|Smaller|_|) a b = if a < b then Some() else None

let compareTemperatures a b = 
   let distanceA = abs a 
   let distanceB = abs b
   match distanceA with
   | Greater distanceB -> b
   | Smaller distanceB -> a
   | _ -> abs a

printfn "%i" (temps |> Seq.reduce compareTemperatures)
```

And that returns -8 instead of 1. It seems correct to me and I can't find the bug but I'm new to F# so I might have make a mistake anywhere and can't see it :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't finish your sentence on equality.  I gather if you have (-n and +n), you wish it to print +n.  But if you have (-n and -n), do you wish it to print -n or +n?

Comment: indeed, I'll update with this. do know what happen, I was sure it was here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you got the comparison the wrong way round - when you write:

```
match distanceA with
| Greater distanceB -> b
| Smaller distanceB -> a
```

Then `distanceA` gets passed as the second parameter to `Greater` and so you are returning `b` (in the first case) in case when `b` is further away from zero. The following will make it work:

```
match distanceA with
| Greater distanceB -> a
| Smaller distanceB -> b
```

That said, using active patterns for this just makes the code unnecessarily complicated (and makes it easy to introduce bugs like this one). The following does the same thing and it is easy to understand and also a lot simpler:

```
let compareTemperatures a b = 
  if abs a > abs b then b else a

temps |> Seq.reduce compareTemperatures
```

I think the lesson here is that pattern matching works really well for things like algebraic data types and option values, but it is not that useful for simple numerical comparisons where `if` works fine!

Comment: it was indeed a swap in the match. I'm not sure how to read it then, is that (for the first matching i my wrong solution) => DistanceA Greater than DistanceB then return a ?

Comment: I'm adding another comment because on your solution with if else you don take the default case in account and when you have -n and n we should return n, becsue of this then you need to add another if else and it's becoming less readable too. But still better than active pattern maybe?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to compare the values, using first the absolute value, then the sign. Here's my one-liner:

```
temps |> Seq.minBy (fun x -> abs x, -sign x)
```

Test case (prints `2`):

```
let li = [-2; 2; -2; 3; -5]
li |> Seq.minBy (fun x -> abs x, -sign x) |> printfn "%d"
```

Comment: It is nice and short. I can't test right now becauseI'm at work, but is this working when you have only the negative value (let's say you add -1 in your test list)? I wonder if it's not always returning the positive value. (sorry still very new with F# and don't know -sign function even I have a good guess)

Comment: Yes. When comparing the numbers, it will create tuples and compare them. For example `3` becomes `(3, -1)` and `-5` becomes `(5, 1)`. If the first elements in the tuple are equal, it will compare the second element. There's `-` in front of `sign` so that positive numbers get `-1` and negative numbers get `1`. The function will return the number that has the smallest tuple.

Comment: If conciseness is the goal, `sign` isn't strictly necessary here.  Just `-x` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This should have been a comment to Thomas' answer, but I'm too stupid for the mobile app...

How about `if abs (2*a-1) > abs (2*b) then b else a`?